# Using MrEngineer13's SnackBar library implementation

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I am using @MrEngineer13's [SnackBar implementation](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar) and was wondering how to capture 2 separate "ActionClick" events - depending on when the actionclick event occurs, I need to do different things.

The builder looks like this -

```
new SnackBar.Builder(this)
.withOnClickListener(this)
.withMessage("This library is awesome!") // OR
.withMessageId(messageId)
.withTypeFace(myAwesomeTypeFace)
.withActionMessage("Action") // OR
.withActionMessageId(actionMsgId)
.withTextColorId(textColorId)
.withBackGroundColorId(bgColorId)
.withVisibilityChangeListener(this)
.withStyle(style)
.withDuration(duration)
.show();`
```

and the onMessageClick takes a "token" parameter -

```
@Override
public void onMessageClick(Parcelable token) {
     }
```

What I am not able to figure out is, how to pass this "token" when the click happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> depending on when the actionclick event occurs, I need to do different things

Handle that in the body of `onMessageClick()`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageClick(Parcelable token) {
  if (shouldIDoX()) {
    doX();
  }
  else {
    doY();
  }
}
```

(where you supply relevant implementations of `shouldIDoX()`, `doX()`, and `doY()`.

> What I am not able to figure out is, how to pass this "token" when the click happens

There is a `withToken()` method on the `Builder` that you can use to supply the `Parcelable` to be passed into `onMessageClick()`. That being said, the JavaDocs describe it as "The token used to restore the SnackBar state", which would make me a bit nervous about messing with it.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot!